# how to create a button dynamically in xamarin c# according to number of data in database. ln my code linear layout declaration is not working

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm trying to create a button dynamically in xamarin c# according to number of data in database.After linear layout declaration entire code is not working.

```
           try
        {                var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetAsync("http://");
            string jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            JSONArray a = new JSONArray(jsonResponse);
            LinearLayout linearLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearlayout1);
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length(); i++)
            {        
                JSONObject json = a.GetJSONObject(i);
                String id = json.GetString("id");
                String name = json.GetString("name");
                String status = json.GetString("status");
                // Toast.MakeText(this, id + name + status, ToastLength.Long).Show();       
                Button button = new Button(this);
                button.Text = name;
                button.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
                button.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.White);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
                layoutParams.BottomMargin = 5;
                button.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
                //Toast.MakeText(this, id, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                linearLayout.AddView(button);
             }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Excep", ToastLength.Long).Show();

        }
```

Comment: What do you mean with "entire code is not working" ?

Comment: i have printed the value of id name and status once i started to call the linearlayout its throwing an exception.

Comment: i don't know how to create a button dynamically in linear layout please help me over this looking forward for a reply..!!

Comment: now the output of above program is "Excep".

Comment: user7379431 change `Toast.MakeText(this, "Excep", ToastLength.Long).Show();` with this: `Toast.MakeText (this, $"{e}", ToastLength.Long).Show ();` and post what you get.

Comment: System.NotlmplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented. at VoltrentNetworks.login.FindViewByld[T] (System.Object myButton1) [0x00001] in C:\xamarin\VoltLogin\VoltLogin WoltLogin.Droid \login.cs:146 at VoltrentNetworks.login +<OnCreate>d__13.MoyeNext [0x001 c7] in C:\xamarin\VoltLogin\VoltLogin WoltLogin.Droid \login.cs:64

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like you're adding it to your view as `children`.

Comment: i don't know how to create a button dynamically in linear layout please help me over this looking forward for a reply..!!

Comment: Just add this line before your for loop ends. (Right after the  Toast.MakeText(this, id, ToastLength.Long).Show();
}):   `linearLayout.AddView(button);`

Comment: Try @apipineda's answer. Haven't tried it but it looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something:

```
    //You need a ViewGroup, you already have it:
    LinearLayout linearLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayout1);

    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject json = a.GetJSONObject(i);
        String id = json.GetString("id");
        String name = json.GetString("name");
        String status = json.GetString("status");

        //You create the instance of your view in this case your Button
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.Text = name;
        button.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
        button.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.White);

        //define the button layout
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);

        //in case you want to modify other properties of the LayoutParams you use the object
        layoutParams.BottomMargin = 5;

        //Assign the layoutParams to the Button.
        button.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;

        //If you want to do something with the buttons you create you add the handle here
        //button.Click += (sender, e) => DoSomething(id);

        //Add the button as a child of your ViewGroup
        linearLayout.AddView(button);
    }
```

And you are done. This should guide you.

Comment: Still I'm getting the same error. Actually the for loop is running in try{}. The output for the code is throwing the exception(catch{}).

Comment: @user7379431 But you haven't indicated the error you are receiving, with out this is kinda difficult to help you.

Comment: System.NotlmplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented. at VoltrentNetworks.login.FindViewByld[T] (System.Object myButton1) [0x00001] in C:\xamarin\VoltLogin\VoltLogin WoltLogin.Droid \login.cs:146 at VoltrentNetworks.login +<OnCreate>d__13.MoyeNext [0x001 c7] in C:\xamarin\VoltLogin\VoltLogin WoltLogin.Droid \login.cs:64